# In 2012, is MSMQ still valid for queueing calls in WCF?

Tags: wcf, concurrency, msmq

I have created a WCF web service that will upload data from SQL Server to our ISeries. When an end user is finished with their data entry (a batch), they will "send" the batch number to the web service. The web service will then upload that data to the ISeries. It cannot be assumed that this will be a quick process and there may be many end users hitting the web service at once. Likewise, because the way the database is setup on the ISeries, I can't upload this data simultaneously because we may run into locks, misfired triggers, etc. So, I want somehow to queue these calls so that they are done in order received.

I have been searching for methods to do this and there's a lot of information in 2011 and earlier discussing MSMQ. Is that the still preferred way to do this? Would Reentrant Concurrency mode be a more "modern" option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of alternative queuing systems. Since you have a SQL Server in place I would recommend using MSMQ. In this combination you can use TransactionScope out-of-the-box to handle transcations spanning your DB and the Queuing system.

From my own experience, MSMQ is a proven and stable technology stack.

Comment: +1 I second that! Using the MSMQ is straight forward and WCF makes it easy to work with it. Strange, I was sure that I already had answered more or less the same, already in the last week. I must have missed to submit it...